# How do I capture an aborted call or is setting the timeout to 0 correct?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mithril.js

I have a JavaScript client that works in Chrome and Firefox, but fails in IE.  Looking at the network trace in the IE debugger it shows that multiple of the AJAX calls have been aborted.

I've been able to get around it by setting the timeout to 0.  I'd like to know if this is the correct way to handle my requests being aborted?  Basically what could go wrong?

My initial thought was that I should capture and resend on error, and if multiple resubmits do not result in a completed request, finally alert the user.  I'd still like to know how to do this even if the setTimeout is the proper way to address my immediate issue.

Also the application will process an excel workbook of addresses, call a web service to add some data to them and then allow the user to download the enhanced file.

This is what I have so far, first in the app.js

```
var requestWithFeedback = function (args) {
$(".loader").removeClass('hidden');

var oldConfig = args.config || function () { };
args.config = function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.token);
  oldConfig(xhr);
  extract: extract;
};

var deferred = m.deferred();
setTimeout(function () { // <== This solved in IE, but is this the way to handle this?
m.request(args).then(deferred.resolve, function(err){
  if (err === "Invalid token!"){
    m.route('/');
  }
})}, 0);

$(".loader").addClass('hidden');
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

From the model.js

```
app.MarkedAddresses.ProcessAddressBatch = function () {
var requestData = {
    Addresses: app.MarkedAddresses.vm.addresses
}
return requestWithFeedback({
    method: "POST"
    , url: "API/server.ashx"
    , data: requestData
    , deserialize: function (value) { return value; }
})
.then(function (value) {
    var responseJSON = $.parseJSON(value);
    $.merge(app.MarkedAddresses.vm.results, responseJSON)

  app.MarkedAddresses.vm.currentRecord(app.MarkedAddresses.vm.results.length); 
  app.MarkedAddresses.vm.progress(Math.max(app.MarkedAddresses.vm.progress(), ~~(app.MarkedAddresses.vm.currentRecord() / app.MarkedAddresses.vm.totalRecords() * 100)));

    m.redraw(); //Force redraw for progress bar

    return value;
},
function (error) { console.log(error) }  // <== I thought error would show up here, but I never hit a breakpoint here.
);
}
```

**Added loops**

```
function process_wb(wb) {
app.MarkedAddresses.vm.results.length = 0; 
$('.descending').removeClass("descending");
$('.ascending').removeClass("ascending");
app.MarkedAddresses.vm.progress(.1);
m.redraw();

var header = mapHeader(wb);

var addressJSON = to_json(wb, header);

app.MarkedAddresses.vm.totalRecords(addressJSON.length);

for (var i = 0; (i < addressJSON.length + 1) ; i += 1000) {
    app.MarkedAddresses.vm.addresses = addressJSON.slice(i, Math.min(((i) + 1000), addressJSON.length));
    app.MarkedAddresses.vm.response(new app.MarkedAddresses.vm.processAddressBatch());
}

}
```

Why isn't the error triggered in the section of the code?
It seems like I should add a deferred section here, but anything I've tried has been a syntax error.

Comment: So you are making multiple Ajax requests at once? What is triggering the Ajax requests to be fired off?

Comment: Whoops.. Thought I added that.. I'll add to the original question, but I'm processing a excel workbook and processing chunks or addresses.

Comment: What's the actual error IE gives you?